# How do I programmatically change keyboard layout with Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

How can I programmatically change the keyboard layout in Cocoa?

Assume I have, say, two active ones "Estonian" and "U.S." in the System Preferences (i.e. those two layouts visible in the keyboard layout menu bar).

So how would I read that those two are available, and how would I programmatically change between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Text Input Source Services](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/TextFonts/Reference/TextInputSourcesReference/Reference/reference.html) if you're on 10.5 or higher. It's based on CoreFoundation, so don't worry it's inside Carbon framework. If you need to support 10.4 or older, you need to use [Keyboard Layout Services](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/KeyboardLayoutServices/Reference/reference.html). I only know the former, so let me explain just that.

You use

```
CFArrayRef sourceList= TISCreateInputSourceList (NULL,false);
```

to get the array of `TISInputSourceRef` corresponding to all the enabled keyboard types. Then you can use other functions to examine them. To select/deselect one, you can use `TISSelectInputSource` and `TISDeselectInputSource`, etc.

Don't forget to `CFRelease` the array you got, though, even in the garbage collected environment, because the garbage-collection of CF objects are not automatic!

Comment: Yikes, Core Foundation :S Looks like I'm going to have to do some reading on that, as I'm only into Objective-C and Cocoa, not the lower-level stuff. But thanks, I'll try messing with it, see how it goes, and then get back to you.

Comment: Don't worry, Core Foundation is just a C API for the OS X object system. It behaves very much like `NSObject`, `NSArray`, etc. In fact `CFArrayRef` can be cast into `NSArray*` and used as such. Apple's documentation is generically very good. Have fun and good luck!